# Converting Mnist dataset in image format

Tags: python, mnist

I want to convert the mnist dataset which is available in .csv file in image format like jpeg or png.

```
from PIL import Image
temp = mnist.train.images[0]
temp=np.reshape(temp,(28,28))
temp=temp*255
im = Image.fromarray(temp).convert('L')
im.save("C:/Users/user/Desktop/ML/image/img.png")
```

I used the above code for converting pixels into image and I am able to convert it into image but the problem is the image is saved in a black and white format.
And in the statement

```
im = Image.fromarray(temp).convert('L')
```

if I use 'RGB' instead of 'L' the image is saved as a black image.
So How I can convert the image into color format.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the integers as packed bytes in a mongoDB in such a way that you can use PIL to turn the packed bytes into an image in the following way.

This code shows how to save 10 test images and then to retrieve one of them and save it as a `.png`.

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient()
>>> db = client.test_database
>>> import csv
>>> from struct import pack
>>> posts = db.posts
>>> with open('mnist_test_10.csv') as mnist_csv:
...     mnist_reader = csv.reader(mnist_csv)
...     for row in mnist_reader:
...         digit = row[0]
...         pixels = pack((-1+len(row))*'B', *[int(_) for _ in row[1:]])
...         post = {'digit': digit, 'pixels': pixels}
...         post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id
...         
>>> record = posts.find_one({'digit':'7'})
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.frombytes('L',(28,28),record['pixels'])
>>> im.save('temp.png')
>>>
```

Comment: im.save('temp.png') would be saving the image in mongoDB database or in any particular folder. Because I want the image to be stored in mongoDB.

Comment: `post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id` stores the image bytes in mongodb. From `record =` onwards in the code is just a demonstration of how the bytes can be retrieved and then used, in this case coverted to a `.png` image and stored as a file.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the answer that some of the details would depend on what purpose you have in mind for the images.